# Emacs ispell goto previous word?

Tags: emacs, ispell

As I'm using <kbd>M-x ispell</kbd> to check LaTeX code
I use <kbd>SPC</kbd> to skip a lot of entries that should not be corrected.
But then I sometimes skip an actual misspelled word.
What's the key to go back with ispell to previous word?

Answer (score 2):

I checked the source code of ispell.el, and unfortunately, there seems to be no key-binding for this (the keys are actually hardcoded in the function `ispell-command-loop`). As a quick hack, if you don't mind your buffer-local mark-ring to be cluttered, you could do something like this:

```
(defadvice ispell-command-loop (after leave-breadcrumbs activate)
  "Leave a trail in the mark-ring when waiting for user input"
  (push-mark (point) t))
```

Then you can always go back to previous errors with C-u C-SPC. Alternatively, you can create your own mark-ring for this function.